# Constructor class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, constructor

Why am I getting this error when I try to compile the class with `main()` in it?

```
Driver.java:7: error: constructor NameParser in class NameParser cannot be applied to given types;  NameParser nameParser = new NameParser(args[0], args[1]);

  required: no arguments

  found: String,String

  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

```
import parsing.*;
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NameParser nameParser = new NameParser(args[0], args[1]);
    }
}
```

```
package parsing;
public class NameParser {
    public static void NameParser(String nameTable, String tokenTable)  {
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static void NameParser` should be `public NameParser`

Comment: Your `NameParser` class only has a default constructor. The method `NameParser` that you defined is **not** a constructor

Answer (score 1):

your constructor is incorrect, should be

```
public NameParser(String nameTable, String tokenTable)  {
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructor doesn't have a *return type*. Your constructor should be:

```
public NameParser(String nameTable, String tokenTable) {

}
```

The one you tried to define is, in fact, a `static` method (*class* method), because of the `static` modifier and the return type `void` (which means that it doesn't return anything).

Also, the error you are getting is because in the line

```
NameParser nameParser = new NameParser(args[0], args[1]);
```

you are calling a constructor with the parameters `(String, String)` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

`public static void NameParser(String nameTable, String tokenTable)` is not a constructor. It is just a static method with a `void` return type.

You should define the contructor as follows:

`public NameParser(String nameTable, String tokenTable)`

Answer (score 0):

Constructor shouldn't have return type and 
name should be same as class name.

in your case

```
NameParser(String nameTable, String tokenTable)
 {

    //some logic will be here

   }
```